# Would it be legal to publish a program to factor large semiprime numbers?

Tags: united-states, software, oregon, hacking, computer

If I somehow figured out a way to factor large semiprime numbers in a reasonable amount of time (don't worry, I haven't; this is hypothetical), would it be legal to publish the code?

This could be problematic because RSA, an encryption algorithm that Internet security is pretty much based on, can be trivially cracked by an attacker with the ability to factor the large semiprime numbers used. An attacker with such ability could quite easily have read and modified the contents of this page while it was being transferred to your browser if they controlled one of the routers the page passed through over the Internet.

Comment: Just saying: It has been done. The question is if you have a machine that factors say 512 bit semiprimes in a reasonable time.

Comment: 891 bits is the current record afaik.

Comment: A little background for context would be nice.

Comment: Background: RSA is a very common encryption method. You can break RSA encryption if you can factor large semiprime numbers. This is possible in theory, but in practice it will take too long; people genera use 1024 but keys and the largest one ever factored was 891 bits. If you came up with a computer program that could factor 1024 bit semiprime numbers in a day instead of thousand years, lots of encryption could be broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sure

But it’s been [done](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm). Admittedly, we don’t yet have the computer to run it for numbers bigger than 15 but the algorithm is ready to go.

Comment: Ah, yes, I remember in the early 1990's looking forward to quantum computers [sic] being able to factor 15. I think they'd already done 6. :)

Answer (score 7):

Since you are asking about US law, the matter is very simple. See [Bernstein v. US](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/case/reporter/F3/176/176.F3d.1132.97-16686.html), 176 F.3d 1132.

> The government defendants appeal the grant of summary judgment to the
> plaintiff, Professor Daniel J. Bernstein ("Bernstein"), enjoining the
> enforcement of certain Export Administration Regulations ("EAR") that
> limit Bernstein's ability to distribute encryption software. We find
> that the EAR regulations (1) operate as a prepublication licensing
> scheme that burdens scientific expression, (2) vest boundless
> discretion in government officials, and (3) lack adequate procedural
> safeguards. Consequently, we hold that **the challenged regulations
> constitute a prior restraint on speech that offends the First
> Amendment**. Although we employ a somewhat narrower rationale than did
> the district court, its judgment is accordingly affirmed.

It might remain [illegal to export](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States#U.S._export_rules) some type of software, but it is not illegal to publish an algorithm.

Comment: "it is not illegal to publish an algorithm" [It seems the SEC disagree](https://home.treasury.gov/news/press-releases/jy0916)

Comment: @User65535
 It seems that th action (which was by the US DoJ, not the SEC) was not to punish **publication** of an algorithm, but rather its **use** as a tool to violate the law, specifically laws against money laundering.

Answer (score -2):

Heh! Well, it may still be illegal to make it available outside the U.S. borders, if you are within them. The "ITAR" business 20+ years ago declared things like the RSA algorithm "munitions", which could not be exported, etc. A bit silly, but, well, ...

(Some people got the Perl code for RSA tattooed onto their arms, etc., ... to "become a munition", ...)

If you really did manage to seriously break RSA, I suspect you'd have some serious people coming to talk to you, and issues about publication would be the last of your worries. Publication may not be "illegal", but it may be against the best interests of national security... That kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't be surprised if this would be considered "born classified," sort of like if Average Joe figured out how to build a nuclear bomb.

Comment: @Someone “born classified” only applies to Restricted Data under the Atomic Energy Act, not to any other type of information.

Comment: The attempt to claim that publication of certain encryption algorithms violateexport regs or similar laws was quashed by the US courts as the answer by user6726 shows.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, ah, well, yes, "there is the law, and current interpretations". Nevertheless, I'll be you a dollar if someone either found an incredible (classical) algorithm, or got a quantum computer to work at interesting scales, "people" would come around to talk to them about it. Maybe it's not a matter of law, but more like "force majeure", and so on. :)

Comment: @paul garrett People came around and talked to the Washington Post and the NY Times about publishing jthe Pentagon Papers. ("People" included the US attorney General.) People came around and talked to Professor Bernstein about publishing encryption algorithms. People talked to *The Progressive* about publishing "The H-Bomb Secret". People talked to Jay M. Near about publishing *The Saturday Press*. In all of these cases, after legal proceedings, publication proceeded.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, oh, I don't doubt that, on some occasions, there is no extra-curricular inhibition of publication of scientific progress, or, indeed, that there were attempts, but that, eventually, the courts upheld a reasonable viewpoint. Nevertheless, I myself would not want to endure the stress (and probably expense) of fighting an arguably illegal imposition by the federal government on my activities. :)

Comment: @paul garrett Indeed, such situations can be quite stressful and costly. In each of the situations I mentioned, government officials attempted to apply strong pressure, including the threat of felony convictions. But the people wanting to publish persevered, and each situation became  landmark case, making things easier for other in similar situations in future. I suggest reading *Minnesota Rag* a good book about the -*Near v Minnesota* case, the earliest of those I have listed.